# Ruby on Rails Select with date range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am trying to get the following sentence to work,

```
User.all.select{ |user| user.created_at === DateTime.yesterday..DateTime.today }

User.all.select{ |user| user.created_at == DateTime.yesterday..DateTime.today }

User.all.select{ |user| user.created_at => DateTime.yesterday..DateTime.today }
```

This doesnt works and prompts a `bad value for range` error.

I am aware that there are more efficient ways to accomplish this and get the same results, but im interested in how to get a select work with a date range

Comment: Please realize that calling ```all.select``` will retrieve all users from the database, and then select from among them in memory. It's hard to imagine any case where that's a good idea.

Comment: @TimScott Excellent observations, but as stated this is only for explanation purposes, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
range = (DateTime.yesterday..DateTime.now)
User.all.select { |user| range.cover?(user.created_at) }
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are in Rails 3, you can do this:

```
User.find(:all, :conditions => {:created_at => DateTime.yesterday.. DateTime.today})
```

Note however this has since been deprecated for this:

```
User.where(:created_at => DateTime.yesterday..DateTime.today)
```

Comment: Excelent thanks, but as i stated, wanted, just for 'fun', to know how to do it with the select method. Cheers!

Comment: Fair enough, but if that is the kind of thing you consider "fun," you really should get out more.